# How to take input in single line in python and storing it into list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting **Runtime Error - NZEC** while running this code online. I searched.. it is because of input format. Please help me out.

```
import math
a=input()
b=int(a)
e=list()
answer=1
for c in range(0,b):
    d=input()
    e.append(d)
for c in range(0,b):
    g=e[c]
    answer=math.fmod(float(float(answer) * float(g)),float((10**9)+7))
print(int(answer))
```

Comment: It works ok for me. Can you share the exception with the stacktrace?

Comment: `e.append(int(d))` would be better like the first input you did.

Comment: @Seba: are you using Python 2 or Python 3. In python 2 that would work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am using python 3 not working

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre could you please share the edited code... not getting right.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I tried with both 2.7, and 3.5. And works for both (assuming that you type digits in the stdin)

Comment: you are right. My bad, bad lead.

Comment: @Seba Could you please share the running code... not working till yet.
Problem is I want to take input till the loop continue in a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to take the second and following inputs in a single line (I guess separated by spaces), you can do the following:

```
import math
a=input()
b=int(a)
answer=1

e = raw_input().split(" ")[:b]

for c in range(0,b):
    g=e[c]
    answer=math.fmod(float(float(answer) * float(g)),float((10**9)+7))
print(int(answer))
```

For instance you would type "3[enter]" then "5 66 77[enter]". Is that what you need?

EDIT: I guess this is some kind of programming exercise. But if needed you can even omit the first input, and request just a list of X numbers separated by spaces:

```
import math
answer=1

for g in raw_input().split(" "):
    answer=math.fmod(float(float(answer) * float(g)),float((10**9)+7))
print(int(answer))
```

Comment: Yes, I want like this only "3[enter]" then "5 66 77[enter]". Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: the question was not so good, Seba had to guess what was your input. We all supposed that you entered just one number.